# Implementation of functions

Tags: python, function

I know this has been a question asked but I cant seem to find it.
Im asking a user for how much snow fell each month so that was easy

```
year=print(input("Hello, what year of snowfall are you checking? "))
count=0
jan=print(input("How much snow fell during the month of January? "))
feb=print(input("How much snow fell during the month of Febuary? "))
mar=print(input("How much snow fell during the month of March? "))
```

but my professor later sent an email that "This should be implemented using ONE input statement, not three."  We are currently learning functions and the use of `def` and I cant find an implementation of them
I came up with this for a "one input line" but I don't think this is how he wanted me to do it

```
j,f,m = print(input("Please enter the snowfall for january, febuary and march here: ")).split()
    j=int(j)
    f=int(f)
    m=int(m)
```

Thanks in advance, before college I knew nothing of programming.

Comment: This is way too broad question, there are infinite ways of doing that.

Comment: Think about defining a list of the month names, and then looping over and requesting an input for each month.  I'm sure your professor means using input() once in the code, not only letting it be executed once.

Comment: devmacrile, that is what he meant, sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this: one with loops and one with functions

With loops:

```
for month in ["January", "February", "March"]:
    print(input("How much snow fell during the month of %s" % month))
```

With functions:

```
def ask(month):
    print(input("How much snow fell during the month of %s" % month))
ask("January")
ask("February")
ask("March")
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the '%s'?

Comment: also, the implementation of the second  "print(input("How much snow fell during the month of %s" % month))" caused the program to ask me for the snowfall months twice.

Comment: The loop and function methods are mutually exclusive and both do the same thing. I was just showing you two ways to do it. Responding to your first comment, `%s` is a string formatting operator. `'%s' % "cow"` is equal to `"cow"`.

Comment: The loop method is probably better because you otherwise would have to add another function call if you wanted to ask for the month of march. Or april. Or May. Etc

Answer (score 0):

```
def getSnowFall(month):
    sfstr = input('Please enter the snow fall for ' + month);
    return int(sfstr);
```

Then call the function for the month.

Comment: this is what I was trying to figure out.  Does that 'return' function restart the function?

Comment: No.  It would return the result of the input string casted to a integer to the caller. I.E. janSnowFall = getSnowFall('January')

Comment: `return` is not a function, that's why it has no brackets. It gives back the following value to the caller.